# How can I use "WITH ROLL UP" to give me a grand total (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

Here is my code for my database

```
SELECT product_name, ((item_price - discount_amount)*quantity) TotalAmount
FROM products, order_items
WHERE products.product_id = order_items.product_id
GROUP BY order_items.product_id
```

I tried doing
    GROUP BY order_items.product_id with rollup 
and all it does is duplicate my last line of output.

Then I tried
    GROUP BY order_items.product_id, product_name with rollup 
and it does a number of weird things

Comment: Can you add some sample data?

Comment: I'm not a fan of ROLLUP. I prefer to use a simple bit of data processing in the presentation layer.